# Spring Data Envers custom metadata

Tags: spring-data, hibernate-envers

I have marked my entity `@Audited` and I can see that it logs the **revision number** and **timestamp** of a new revision, but how can I add custom metadata? I believe it must be possible since `org.springframework.data.RevisionMetadata` has the `getDelegate()` method with the following Javadoc:

> Returns the underlying revision metadata which might provider more detailed implementation specific information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a pure Hibernate Envers perspective, if you want your revision entity to store additional context information about a revision such as who modified the entities or perhaps a reason for the change, then you would want to do this through a `RevisionListener` callback combined with a custom extension to `DefaultRevisionEntity`.

For example:

```
@Entity
@RevisionEntity(CustomRevisionListener.class)
public class CustomRevisionEntity extends DefaultRevisionEntity {
  private String userName;
  /* getter/setters */
}

public class CustomRevisionListener implements RevisionListener {
  @Override
  public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {
     CustomRevisionEntity cre = (CustomRevisionEntity)revisionEntity;
     cre.setUserName( UserContextHolder.getUserContext().getUserName() );
  }
}
```

Envers will detect the special annotated `@RevisionEntity` entity-class and use it.  It will also detect the specified `RevisionListener` implementation and will instantiate and callback to this class when a new revision entity is constructed.

Unfortunately, I can't speak for how this translates usage-wise with respect toward`spring-data` and `spring-data-envers` projects.

Comment: They won't let me edit the answer so this is how you can get the metadata with Spring Data Envers (yay for formatting): `Long entityId = 1L;
Revision revision = enversRepository.findLastChangeRevision(entityId);
CustomRevisionEntity metadata = revision.getMetadata().getDelegate();`